# Extra spaces in e-mail subject using chilkat

Tags: c++, email, character-encoding, email-headers, chilkat

We're using Chilkat mail for Visual C++ 8.0. We have a problem with decoding extra spaces in subject for some e-mails. The subject in these e-mails has got few encoded words like (two below):

```
=?utf-8?Q?Some text in he?=  =?utf-8?Q?re?=
```

According to RFC2047 this subject should look like "Some text in here", but chilkat decoding it as "Some text in he  re". Two spaces which should be ignored between encoded words are visible in decoded subject.

If anyone knows how to solve this issue, I'll be grateful for some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem by removing extra spaces between `?=` and `=?` tags in received e-mails before they're stored in our database.